# how to limit project grafika circular continuous camera recorder maximum seconds?

Tags: android, video, grafika

there is a `MAX_LENGTH` value that we can set.
that value limits the recording approximately.. sometimes it can get up to double.
so lets say i set the value of `MAX_LENGTH` to 15 then launch the app and start recording sometimes it exceed that limitation and get to 30! 
that limitation mechanism is broken.. 
there is a way to hard limit it so it won't exceed `MAX_LENGTH` ever?
thanks

Comment: Limiting the amount of data recorded into the buffer is tricky. Limiting the amount of data written to disk is easier. Your best bet would be to store more data than you need in the circular buffer, then only write the desired portion of it to disk when "capture" is clicked. I think you could do this by modifying `CircularEncoderBuffer#getFirstIndex()`, which returns the index of the *oldest* sync frame, to return the one that yields N seconds of video.

Comment: Sounds way more interesting than the other solution.. i'll try it sometime.. thanks. now i am cropping the video from the end which = more job to the device and bigger "Saving..." times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

Grafika is experimental and has no support. From the README file:

> It's not stable.
>
> It's not polished or well tested. Expect the UI to be ugly and awkward.
>
> It's not intended as a demonstration of the proper way to do things. The code may handle edge cases poorly or not at all. Logging is often left enabled at a moderately verbose level.
>
> It's barely documented.
>
> It's generally just not supported.

**Second**

The [code comment](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java#L218) itself specifies that the FPS can be **variable**:

> Opens a camera, and attempts to establish preview mode at the specified width and height.
>
> Sets mCameraPreviewFps to the expected frame rate (which might actually be variable).

**Source Code**: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java

Comment: I saw that already but there isn't any way beside that? (out side of grafika)
Thanks for you reply

Comment: Not that Grafika provides. It is experimental stuff, I guess you could take the source code and try to fix the issue you're having, but that's it.

Comment: BTW i can always trim the video with ffmpeg if it exceeds its boundaries :)

Comment: If that helps, feel free to accept my answer. Regards.

Comment: of course. JTLYK i've succeeded with the use of MP4Parser. thanks again